# Titan: Connect to Elasticsearch from another machine

Tags: elasticsearch, titan

I'm using Titan 1.0.0 with Elasticsearch. I have Titan (with DynamoDB backend) working on an EC2 machine.

My main goal is connect to that Titan instance through another EC2 machine using Java.

Unfortunately I cannot connect to this machine.

My Titan instance is configured using a properties file. Here is a snippet of the Elasticsearch configuration:

```
# elasticsearch config
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.directory=/path/to/elasticsearch
index.search.elasticsearch.interface=NODE
index.search.elasticsearch.ext.node.data=true
index.search.elasticsearch.ext.node.client=false
index.search.elasticsearch.ext.node.local=false
```

This starts a full node holding data.

Now I want to connect to this node's Elasticsearch from another machine. My configuration file for this is:

```
storage.backend= com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager
storage.hostname=10.0.0.249
storage.port=8182

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.elasticsearch.interface=TRANSPORT_CLIENT
index.search.elasticsearch.ext.node.data=false
index.search.elasticsearch.ext.node.client=true
index.search.hostname=10.0.0.249:9200


storage.dynamodb.client.endpoint=https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

## DynamoDB client configuration: credentials
storage.dynamodb.client.credentials.class-name=com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
storage.dynamodb.client.credentials.constructor-args=
```

When I attempt to connect using Java through this line:

```
graph=TitanFactory.open("conf/dynamodb_remote.properties")
```

I get an error saying:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:55)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:473)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:460)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:147)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1805)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:123)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:62)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$open.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:44)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:198)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClusterAdminClient.execute(InternalTransportClusterAdminClient.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClusterAdminClient.health(AbstractClusterAdminClient.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.health.ClusterHealthRequestBuilder.doExecute(ClusterHealthRequestBuilder.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.<init>(ElasticSearchIndex.java:201)
    ... 49 more
```

I checked using `wget` and seems like ports 9200 and 9201 are working but 9300 is not. And probably that's why the issue exists.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

A couple suggestions based on the Titan configuration [documentation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/titan-config-ref.html#_index)

1. `index.search.hostname` should just be the hostname or IP address. It should not contain the port.
2. `index.search.port` if you decide to specify it, you should use `9300` or your Elasticsearch's value for the transport TCP port.
3. `index.search.elasticsearch.cluster-name` should match the `cluster.name` in the Elasticsearch config.

**Updated**: This seemed to work for me. In `$TITAN_HOME/conf/mytitan.properties`, I configured the indexing backend like this:

```
storage.backend=berkeleyje
storage.directory=../db/mytitan/berkeleyje
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.index-name=mytitan
index.search.elasticsearch.interface=NODE
index.search.conf-file=mytitan-elasticsearch.yml
```

And then `$TITAN_HOME/conf/mytitan-elasticsearch.yml` looks exactly like a regular ES configuration:

```
cluster.name: TitanElasticsearch
network.name: u1401
network.host: 192.168.14.101
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["192.168.14.101"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
node.name: u1401
node.master: true
node.data: true
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
path.data: ./db/mytitan/elasticsearch
```

When I attempted to specify these properties with the prefix `index.search.elasticsearch.ext...`, the Transport TCP port didn't start as you noted earlier.

Comment: The problem is that the port `9300` is not opened. I checked with `netstat` on gremlin-server machine and it's not open. Only `9200` and `9201`.

Comment: It is a port range from 9300-9400 by default. Match the ES java process by the pid when you do the `netstat -plent` and figure out which ports it is using.

Comment: ES is listening to two ports, `9200` and `9201`. They both are listening to HTTP requests. I guess this has to do with the way I configured the gremlin-server. What do you think?

Comment: How did you configure the ES `elasticsearch.yml` for TCP transport? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html

Comment: The configuration lines are already in the question, please have a look. I started it through the configuration file of `dynamodb.properties`.